# Appcelerator Titanium Android background location service

Tags: android, background, geolocation, appcelerator

I am trying to make an app , where if the user enters a particular region, he will get an alert. And that will work even if the app is in background.

I found Ti.App.iOS.backgroundService to do that for iphone but how to start the background service in android and how to present local notification kind thing when particular latitude and longitude is found.

so basically my questions are :-

1. background location service in android
2. android equivalent for localnotification

Comment: So that bounty question you had. You got it working using the backgroundService? Nice. I don't believe there are equivalents just yet but I also haven't read up on the Android `intents` the Appcelerator team has been pushing so much recently to use. They may solve your issue as I understand they do some background processing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For background geo on Android I use the below strategy.

1) In my app.js I add an Titanium.App.addEventListener that contains my geo logic

Kitchen Sink Sample https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/app_events.js

2) I then create a ServiceIntent that fires every 15 minutes

Kitchen Sink Sample https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/android_services.js

Please note this service.js you call needs to be in your android folder, even if you have an android only project.

3) The service checks if the individual has moved more then 1KM, if they have it fires the App Event defined in step 1.

Using this strategy and adjusting my service time and distance calculation I've been able to reduce most of my battery drain issues that I had with the built in location event with distance filter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: great .. thanks a lot.. after searching a lot here and there and telling myself a lots of times that there should be some other easier way, I finally tried your solution and found that its easy.. it works .. and works like charm... thanks a lot.. I still have to do a lot of changes to it but I have finally found the way and now just have to start my car and drive on it