# Appcelerator Titanium background service geolocation for Android

Tags: android, titanium, socket.io, appcelerator

As far as I know, Titanium only allows to run code inside a bg.js file at a specified interval.
Is it a limitation of Appcelerator Titanium?
Is there a way to execute code as long as the service is running as you can do in java or is there a module to do that?

For example, is it possible to run socket.io.client inside the Titanium Android service?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please refer to this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786489/appcelerator-titanium-android-background-location-service

Comment: Please refer to this comment:2) I then create a ServiceIntent that fires every 15 minutes

Comment: This is my problem and I've already seen this question before sending.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how to proceed and you could give me an example of a service which don't use "interval" to execute code.